# Is there any tested "Word2Vector" code example in java or python?

Tags: word2vec

I want tried couple of examples to learn `word2Vec` working by doing implementation but none of them worked out for me. I have tried `dl4j` and other `word2vector` examples. They all have some compilation issues and results are not same as the ones posted. Please help me and provide some tested and working example code.

Comment: what have the issues been with deeplearning4j?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I stronly advice to use Python and gensim.
This two articles should be helpful:

http://rare-technologies.com/doc2vec-tutorial/ Here rememeber to read **IMPORTANT NOTE**, some parts of the API of gensim has been updated recently, but it is really informative tutorial.

https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/doc2vec-IMDB.ipynb - new API with descriptions.

Answer (score 3):

Deeplearning4j implements a distributed form of Word2vec for Java and Scala, which works on Spark with GPUs.

http://deeplearning4j.org/word2vec.html#code